# Rss feed in drupal 7

Tags: rss, drupal-7

I have rss feed in my views. But somewhy rss doesnt show all fields that i selected. Feed shows only Title.
here is code of rss.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://localhost/plasma/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"> <channel> <title>Репортажи</title>
 <link>http://localhost/plasma/</link>
 <atom:link rel="self" href="http://localhost/plasma/reports/rss.xml" />
 <item> <title>&lt;a href=&quot;/plasma/node/40&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&lt;/a&gt;</title>
 <source url="http://localhost/plasma/reports/rss.xml">Репортажи</source>
 <yandex:full-text>&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum&lt;/p&gt;
</yandex:full-text>
 <yandex:genre> &amp;nbsp;&lt;a href=&quot;/plasma/taxonomy/term/3&quot; typeof=&quot;skos:Concept&quot; property=&quot;rdfs:label skos:prefLabel&quot;&gt;tag1&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href=&quot;/plasma/taxonomy/term/4&quot; typeof=&quot;skos:Concept&quot; property=&quot;rdfs:label skos:prefLabel&quot;&gt;tag2&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href=&quot;/plasma/taxonomy/term/5&quot; typeof=&quot;skos:Concept&quot; property=&quot;rdfs:label skos:prefLabel&quot;&gt;tag3&lt;/a&gt;</yandex:genre>
</item>
 <item> <title>&lt;a href=&quot;/plasma/node/39&quot;&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet&lt;/a&gt;</title>
 <source url="http://localhost/plasma/reports/rss.xml">Репортажи</source>
 <yandex:full-text>&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&lt;/p&gt;
</yandex:full-text>
 <yandex:genre> &amp;nbsp;</yandex:genre>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Ps im using Yandex elements, to fit yandex's requirements for RSS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the feed is being chached? Did you try clearing cache?